# popup gets closed automatically

Tags: javascript

I have to refresh my parent window once I am done with the changes in the popup window, for which I use :

```
 <BODY onunload="opener.location.reload();">
```

But this closes my window on any event, like save, whereas I don't want to get it close. I want to close my window only by clicking window close or by clicking close button in my jsp with "Javascript".

For closing thru "Close" button.

**JS :**

```
function closeAndRefresh(){
    opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close(); 
}
```

[image]

Comment: unload will fire every time page resources are getting cleared. i.e.. not only during browser close, but also on postbacks. You need to handle that too.

Comment: Please provide some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem

JS:

```js
var myclose = false;

function ConfirmClose()
{
    if (event.clientY < 0)
    {
       myclose=true;
    }
}

function HandleOnClose()
{
    if (myclose==true) 
    {
     opener.location.href = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>parent_jsp_path";
        window.close();
    }   
}
```

HTML:

```
<BODY onbeforeunload="ConfirmClose();" onunload="HandleOnClose();">
```